# jquery enable/disable text box based on radiobutton

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

In my page (jsp) i have a radiobutton group and a textbox (which is disabled initially).

- Whenever the user clicks on a radio button the textbox should be enabled
- and when the user clicks on some other radio button the textbox should again get disabled.

I am able to enable the initially disabled checkbox with the code below.

```
$("#DevGroup_OTHER").click(function(){          
    $("#otherDevText").attr("disabled","");
})
```

My questions:

- But how can i disable the textbox again?
- Is there a simpler solution using jQuery?

regards

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Always disable it (for every radio button), then re-enable it if the radio button is the one that enables the textbox. Unless the user is on a machine built in 1980, it will be so fast, not one will ever know.

```
$('radio').click(function() { 
    $("#otherDevText").prop("disabled",true);
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'enable_textbox') {
        $("#otherDevText").prop("disabled",false);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, if there are multiple radio buttons that will enable the textbox:

```js
$('input:radio').click(function() { 
  $("#otherDevText").prop("disabled",true);
  if($(this).hasClass('enable_tb')) {
      $("#otherDevText").prop("disabled",false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="DevGroup_OTHER">
  <input type="radio" id="d1" name="r1" value="d1">dev1 <br /> 
  <input type="radio" id="d2" name="r1" value="d2">dev2 <br/> 
  <input type="radio" id="d3" name="r1" value="d3" class="enable_tb"> enable
</fieldset>
<br />
<input id="otherDevText" name="tb1" disabled="disabled"
       value="some Textbox value" type="text">
```

Make sense?

Comment: thank u farris, that's even better.
another problem for me is i am using spring so instead of 
<input type="radiobutton">
i used <form:radiobutton ....>

any ideas on selecting all the radio buttons.

thanks again.

Comment: yes i found one, selector by tag name.
also, what will be there when we say $(this) in your code? is it the first selector ($('radio')) or second one ($("#otherDevText"))

i am getting some command object name coz i use spring MVC!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring MVC, but I'm quite sure that by the jquery has a chance to interact with the code, the element *will* be `<input type="radiobutton">`. The answer to your second question: `$(this)` will be referencing the clicked `$('radio')` element.

Comment: thank u, yes it is referring to the radiobutton clicked.
but in my case "id" attribute is returning some wired result probably because spring MVC tag.
any way, thanx for quick reply!

Comment: @KyleFarris my edit could be considered an edge case regarding valid edits; if it misrepresents your answer then i apologize, feel free to remove it.

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#some_other_radiobutton").click(function(){
  $("#otherDevText").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

Comment: yeah, but now i have to write this block for all other radiobuttons

Comment: Why don't you just put a class on all the other radio buttons "disables-text" and hook up the click handler to that class?  Just a thought, I'm a jQuery novice.

Comment: Larry is right. If you need to group radio buttons together use classes or put them in a common container (div for example).