# Disable a check based on a radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have some radio buttons in 1 group and checkboxes in another group.  Based on the radio selection I want to disable the accompanying checkbox in group 2 see
    [`Jfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasMoreCoder/h9ttapmz/)

so if you select Employment, full-time in the radio buttons you cannot select it below in the checkbox listing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasMoreCoder/h9ttapmz

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h9ttapmz/2/) ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently you do not provide the code in your answer. Your fiddle contains code that is not needed to demonstrate your use case. And in my opinion you are better served if you learn how to fish instead of getting a free fish. By that i mean that if you explain / describe what you do not understand than the answer will try to explain the concept (fishing) rather than the answer (free fish).

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery enable/disable text box based on radiobutton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531747/jquery-enable-disable-text-box-based-on-radiobutton)

Comment: @BuddhistBeast yes but how do I do it for all the rest of the checkboxes?

Comment: Are you referring to something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/h9ttapmz/3/) ? And I would follow @threeFourOneSixOneThree suggestions above as well.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast you answered my question however please explain to me how:

    $("[name='" + valPicked + "']").parent().hide();

the parent() syntax works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `prop` to set the `disabled` attribute.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', 1);
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/h9ttapmz/1/